# Execute robot framework testsuite twice

Tags: java, maven, robotframework

Am new to robot framework, i would like to execute same testsuite, which contains 10 testcases two times. i.e first run using http and the second run using https.

am making use of maven-robotframework-plugin to call robot in an automated manner.

Can anyone please suggest, the way one can proceed on this?

example
Testsuite - 10 testcases

First run - execute all 10 testcases from above testsuite using http
Second run - execute all 10 testcases from above same testsuite using https

Am already maintaining a variable file where am setting many other variables, i shall pass as secure variable as mentioned below by (Helio). However, am still unable to understand as to how this change will help testsuite execute two times, without explicitly calling mvn robotframework:run twice once, with secure:False and other time with secure:True. I would like to execute both cases in a single execution run. Can you please explain?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass a variable to robot. On Suite setup you will set the "http" or "https" depending on that variable. For example:

```
robot -v secure:False Testsuite
```

or

```
robot -v secure:True Testsuite
```

On your suite setup you would set URL prefix like:

```
${PROTOCOL}=    Set Variable If    ${secure}    https://    http://
Set Suite Variable    ${PROTOCOL}
```

Your Tests and Keywords would use it like, for example:

```
Open Browser    ${PROTOCOL}thewebaddressundertest.org/    ${BROWSER}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.

Thank you for responding.
Am already maintaining a variable file where am setting many other variables, i shall pass as secure variable as mentioned above. However, am still unable to understand as to how this change will help testsuite execute two times, without explicitly calling mvn robotframework:run twice once, with secure:False and other time with secure:True. I would like to execute both cases in a single execution run. 

 Can you please explain?

Comment: That will be possible if using Data Driven test, putting the Test logic into a template and creating a data table with the  two settings.Or you can create a two Test Cases for each setting.

Comment: Thank for your response. I need to understand this approach and make use of it.